# IIS Url Rewrite Match not working without Condition

Tags: .net, regex, xml, iis

I have established a few examples, the first is a long hand version that uses a `Condition` element to capture the rest of the url I need. This works, but I don't understand why the following more concise examples won't work.

```
   <rule name="my-videos">
    <match url="(.*)(trips\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/\d{4})" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="my-videos(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}/videogallery{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>
```

---

Then I have this example with one small change, but then breaks and doesn't match my test urls.

See end of `Match Url`

```
d{4}\/)
```

and See reference `Action Url`

```
{R:2}/videogallery
```

```
<rule name="my-videos">
    <match url="(.*)(trips\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/\d{4}\/)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="my-videos(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}videogallery{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

---

Then Ideally the combined final version without the `Condition` element

```
  <rule name="my-videos">
    <match url="(.*)(trips\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/\d{4}\/)my-videos(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}videogallery{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

---

Here are some example test that should replace `my-videos` with `videogallery`

Requested: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/my-videos`

Expected: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/videogallery`

Requested: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/my-videos?fullscreen=true`

Expected: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/videogallery?fullscreen=true`

Requested: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/my-videos/vines`

Expected: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/videogallery/vines`

Requested: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/my-videos/vines?fullscreen=true`

Expected: `trips/my-adventures/asia/india/2018/videogallery/vines?fullscreen=true`

Comment: Can you please add into your examples to which url do you want redirect. It will help me to build better rule for you

Comment: All set @victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is doing exactly what you need:

```
<rule name="my-videos" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*trips\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/[\w-]+\/\d{4}\/)my-videos(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}videogallery{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: It looks like the problem with my version was the initial .* in the match, if anyone reads this in the future to analyze why it didn't work. I was able to actually take Victor's example with out the stopProcessing="true" and it still works

Comment: Yes, `stopProcessing` is not required. But IMHO, it is better to have it for better understanding and support huge list of rules in the future, because if `stopProcessing="true"`, it means that no more subsequent rules will be processed and the URL produced by this rule will be passed to the IIS request pipeline.